# Use ruby each method and store unique results in their own variables

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, iterator, each

I am fairly new to the world of programming and would appreciate some help in executing the following:

I want to use a '.each' statement to iterate through some data.  From there, I need to store each iteration separately.  Please see coding example below.

```
array1 = [] 
array2 = [] 
array3 = [] 
array4 = [] 
array5 = [] 
array6 = [] 
array7 = [] 
array8 = [] 
array9 = [] 
array10 = [] 

@images_array.each do |info| 
 t = info[:title] 
 a = info[:artist] 
 m = info[:medium] 
 c = info[:collection] 
 Array.new << t << a << m << c
end
```

Just to be clear, I have 10 arrays.  I want to store the title, artist, medium, and collection information of 10 different items in their own arrays.  How can I add on to my each method to allow this to be executed dynamically? The last line of code would allow me to do away with the 10 arrays up top. The problem with the Array.new method, however, is I have no way of retrieving a specific array.  The items are neatly stored but there is no variable storing the arrays.

Also, if you can think of a better method of doing this, please share that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the below approach:

```
@images_array.each_with_object([]) do |info,a| 
 a.push(info.values_at(:title,:artist,:medium,:collection))
end
```